# Как присвоить кнопке-картинке метод submit?

Tags: php

```
<a href="register.php"><img src="img/register.jpg" width="262" height="98" /></a>
```

Сделал вот так. Но как с его помощью отправлять данные при нажатии. Т.е хочу аналог:

```
<input type="submit" />
```

Comment: Можете назначит id для кнопки, и применить css к этому id, только не забудьте обнулить рамку border: 0px; и background: none; после укажите свой(переопределите).

Comment: Ещё раз, не нужно извращений, создаёте форму, кнопке даёте id, и этому id присваеваете стили, на background ставите картинку из тега img, выставляете ширину и высоту кнопке и всё! В обработчике формы указываете register.php

Comment: Сделал так:
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
(диез)button
{
 background-image: url(img/register.jpg);
}
</style>

<div id="button"><input type="submit" name="submit" id=/></div>

НИЧЕГО =|

Comment: Уберите button, и id присвойте input'у.

Comment: вам правильно всё советуют, вот пример даже http://jsfiddle.net/nEyAc/

Answer (score 1):

```
  onclick="form_id.submit()";
```

form_id-ccылка на вашу форму ,которую хотите отправить(делается через поиск по DOM)

Comment: а на php нельзя? Это кажись js

да и т.е ссылка на вашу форму??? Я это не понял

Comment: Это и есть js и это то что нужно. 
`form_id=document.getElementById('your_form_id')` или `document.forms.your_form_name`

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="register.php">
<button type="submit" style="background: url('img/register.jpg'); height: 98px; width: 262px;" />
</form>
```